# ¿Cómo puedo darle estilo a la etiqueta options en un select con css?

Tags: html, css

He estado intentando cambiar el estilo de border-radius a las opciones de mi select pero no tengo resultado alguno.
Hasta ahorita lo he estado intentando así:

```
.form-select option{
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los estilos de los `option` son muy limitados y su soporte cambia considerablemente de un navegador a otro. Otra historia es si estás usando una librería/biblioteca que genere un select personalizado. Porque entonces no son `option`... En cualquier caso, deberías editar la pregunta para añadir más datos (p.e. ¿cómo quieres que se vea? ¿podrías añadir un [mcve]?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respuesta corta: No se puede, el elemento options es un elemento dependiente del sistema operativo, y te lo va pintar, como lo pinta el SO. La única opcion que le conozco de personalizacion es el tamaño de la fuente, el color y creo que el color de fondo del select.

Respuesta larga: Podes hacer una lista que te funcione como lista desplegable a la que podes dar estilo libremente con CSS, y con JS manipulas los eventos si necesitas capturar un elemento de la lista al que den click para seleccionarlo por ejemplo.